# can I use texture sheet for loading image without cocos2d

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I want to use a Texture Sheet in a normal IOS project, just like we use Testure Sheet with cocos2d.
  We know that, with cocos2d-iphone we can use it like:

```
 [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"target.plist"];
 CCSpriteBatchNode *spriteSheet = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"target.png"];
 [self addChild:spriteSheet];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not use CCSpriteFrameCache and CCSpriteBatchNode without also using Cocos2D in full.

You can however load the texture atlas yourself, but it'll be a lot of coding/testing. Since TexturePacker supports JSON and generic XML as output formats there's a possibility that someone has already written a texture atlas loader class for generic OpenGL ES apps.